# Custom Authentication - WS02 Identity

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am planning to use WSO2 Identity Server as an Oauth2 provider. However the authentication is to be provided by my enterprise service which uses SOAP Protocol.
Basically I have to send a username/password combination to my service and it provides an authentication response. I understand that I need to implement a custom authenticator but I am not sure how to plug into ws02 IS, having read some of the custom auth docs. The questions are the following

1. Should I implement a LocalApplicationAuthenticator or FederatedApplicationHandler ?
2. I understand there is a method called canHandle() in AuthenticationHandler but not sure what to write in my scenario.
3. What are the various configurations that I need to apply to make custom authentication handler work?
4. Can I build my custom authentication handler as a normal jar file since I am not comfortable building OSGI bundles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to implement a custom user store, see:

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.be/2013/09/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html

there is a method 'doAuthenticate' you may implement as you see fit.

Have fun

g.